# Already made a FB Page, but likes from my page aren't associated with it

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

So I have a facebook page and a username /llamafont so I obviously want to keep that url.

I have had the like button on sub pages (you save phrases and can like/share them on FB) since before I made the page on FB.

When I have added the like button to my homepage for my base url, it shows 62k likes - GREAT! However on my facebook page i only have 107 - I guess these are the people who liked the page directly on FB?

How can I make the 62K likes show up on my page in facebook? Do I need to add in all the meta og: stuff? Right now I only have og:image in there.

Have I screwed it up for good? Or can I make FB recognize the likes somehow? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 62k likes you have are for a Graph Object (your website) and you're trying to migrate them to your Page on Facebook, then yes - you're out of luck.

However, if you have 62k likes on your Page on Facebook, and you want those likes to migrate over to your website, that's pretty easy.  In the `fb:like` widget, you just set the URL to the URL of your Page on Facebook: `www.facebook.com/llamafont`

Comment: I think his situation is for your first statement. Sorry, but yes you "screwed it up for good".